# Determine the start of a selection in a TableView?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a TableView in my QML:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

TableView {
    id: table
    selectionMode: Controls_1.SelectionMode.ContiguousSelection

    function onTableSelectionChanged() {
        console.log(selection)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to determine the start and the end of the selection?

E.g. whether the user is selecting items from low index to high index or from high index to low index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the onSelectionChanged signal from table.selection next to table.selection.forEach to implement an algorithm that calculates the required indexes:

```
Connections {
    target: table.selection
    onSelectionChanged:{
        console.log("Change Selection")
        if(table.selection.count > 0){
            var start = table.rowCount;
            var end = 0;
            table.selection.forEach(function(rowIndex){
                if(rowIndex < start)
                    start = rowIndex;
                if(rowIndex > end)
                    end = rowIndex
            })
            console.log("start: ", start, "end: ", end)
        }
    }
}
```